# wcf asynchronous concurrent call raised timeout exception

Tags: wcf, concurrency

I am making 10 concurrent asynchronous WCF service call from a SilverLight application using multiple threads at the same time.

The WCF service will take 30 seconds to process each call from the client.

When the third thread makes a call to WCF server it gives timed out exception. When I change the send timeout configuration to 10 minutes, it is working fine for all threads.

So my confusion is, is WCF considering the timeout configuration for all the concurrent calls commonly. Please note that I am using basic HTTP binding.

Comment: How is the service defined? What instancing mode are you using?

Comment: Default per session context and single concurrent mode

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is only a single service instance processing your calls. This would happen if (as you say in comments) you have per-session instancing and concurrency set to single.

The calls are treated as belonging to the same client session, and so they are being queued and processed in turn by a single threaded, single service instance. So any requests which don't get dispatched before the client timeout are failed.

You should set the instancing to per-call, this will mean that you will get a service instance per request, so all 10 calls should be processed concurrently.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Tom thanks for your reply, I have tried with percall also, but I am getting the same exception after sometimes

Comment: @xavier What is the nature of the work done in the service operation? Is there dependence downstream on a shared resource?

Comment: We are just calling stored procedure from service which will take nearly 30sec to process each time

Comment: @xavier What if you have multiple threads call the stored procedure at the same time? Does it cause any contention on the DB?

Comment: Thanks for reply, am also thought that, so I have created a same wcf service just like our production wcf service but in my sample service instead of sp, I just set thread.sleep to 30 seconds, here also I got the same issue

Comment: @xavier Are you running this in visual studio?

Comment: Tom, service was hosted in iis, but I am running the Silverlight application from visual studio

Comment: @xavier so are you saying that the behaviour is identical with IntanceContextMode.PerCall and InstanceContextMode.PerSession?

Comment: Tom, instancecontextmode was percall and concurrent mode is single,

Comment: @xavier, my question was is the behavior identical for both instancing modes? Forget about concurrency for a second.

Comment: Yes it was identical to both modes